# SET or VARCHAR for list of tags in a MySQL photos table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb

I just discovered the SET column type for MySQL tables. I have a photos table with ARIA engine where I want to store tags/keywords for each photo.

Now I use a VARCHAR type and then find the photos with a MATCH query and a FULLTEXT INDEX, the tags are space separated like "one two three".

When I use SET, I could possibly use tags with spaces, like "a tag with spaces, another one", but how fast would this be? And can I use FIND IN SET to list photos by tag and also list all tags from a range of photos?

Which is the better choice for tags, SET, VARCHAR or even another type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither

Add another table for tags with one row per tag and photo

- either just `(photo_id, tag)` - `tag` is varchar (or maybe enum, but then it is harder to add more tags), so if two photos have the same tag, there is some redundancy
- or two tables - `(tag_id, tag)` and `(photo_id, tag_id)` where each tag is unique, so no duplication of texts, and the second table just links tags to photos, thats more effective but a bit more complex

Do not store multiple values in one column if you want to work with them (search by them etc.) - a database is not just a CSV storage and this is what rows and joins are for. It's called *Normalization* - learn about it and it will save you from many headaches.

Comment: I had the two tables solution, but it became slow (12000 rows in pic_tag table) and was a bit more difficult to update, edit , delete tags. now with fulltext index it seems much faster and easier to show all photos for 'tag', 'Tag', 'taG' and so on. that is why I changed this yesterday to try if it would be better.

Comment: Did you have proper indexes on those tables? And was the `tag` column defined with a case-insensitive colation? Just a `WHERE tag = 'tag'` should use index and be really fast. 12000 rows should be not enough to worry about performance with proper indexing and sensible queries.

Comment: Yes I had indices but I am not sure if they were right. The tags table was case sensitive because some users wanted to have 'ArtistNamE' or something and others perhaps 'artistname'. It was slower because I want to show all photos of the same TAG and tag and taG summarized. The get-the-pics-query went from about 6-10ms to 2-3ms now, i think. I had to get all tag-ids and then all photos with `WHERE IN (1, 2..)` . And updating tags is easier now. Perhaps you are right. I just thought I found I better way with VARCHAR or SET...

Comment: You can have columns with different collations in the same table. And the way the string is stored does not change with a collation, so you can have `ArtistName` for one photo and `artistNAME` for other one with the `(photo_id, tag)` table and still search all combinations. And you should use JOIN to photos, not WHERE IN - `SELECT <photo columns> FROM photos p JOIN tags t USING(photo_id) WHERE t.tag = 'artistname' GROUP BY photo_id`

Comment: I think I had something like this (2 queries): `SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag COLLATE(utf-8-unicode-ci) tag` and then `SELECT pic_columns FROM pic_tag JOIN pics ON pics.id = pic_tag.pic_id WHERE pic_tag.tag_id IN ($tag_ids)` I will try it with just a (photo_id, tag) table like you wrote.

Comment: I prefer (photo_id, tag varchar).  The varchar is not so bulky as to give a performance issue over tag_id, and the other reasons for "normalizing" are too weak to worry about.  (photo_id, tag_id)+(tag_id, tag) adds complexity and slows things down.

Comment: (photo_id, tag) needs two indexes:  `PRIMARY KEY(tag, photo_id)` and `INDEX(photo_id, tag)`.  Make it InnoDB so the PK is clustered and efficient.  The `INDEX` is for maintenance.  Do not add `auto_increment`.